# Disable vertical scroll in scrollview when scrolling it horizontally

Tags: ios

I have a scroll view .I want to scroll it in both direction horizontal and vertical.But when i am scrolling the subview is bouncing as both scrolling are enabled. how to mange this issue like when i am scrolling the view vertically,horizontal scroll should be disabled.

Comment: That's called "scroll direction lock".

Answer (score 1):

Set the directionalLockEnabled property to YES.

However,

> If the drag direction is diagonal, then scrolling will not be locked
>   and the user can drag in any direction until the drag completes.

Answer (score 0):

Set `scrollview.directionalLockEnabled` to `YES`

> Note: If this property is **NO**, scrolling is permitted in both
>   horizontal and vertical directions. If this property is **YES** and the
>   user begins dragging in one general direction (horizontally or
>   vertically), the scroll view disables scrolling in the other
>   direction. If the drag direction is diagonal, then scrolling will not
>   be locked and the user can drag in any direction until the drag
>   completes. The default value is **NO**